# Need to make a grid this on UIKit using a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, grid, uikit, swift5

I want to make a grid in the photo. How can I achieve this? Can you tell me where to look? Googled everything but found nothing, except through CoreGraphics, but that's not an option I'm considering. [image]

Comment: That's a basic UICollectionView. Do you have each part of the image, or do you need first to crop it into multiple smaller images? what have you tried exactly? If you don't need to scroll, StackViews can be used to. Do you need interactions with the parts?

Comment: I don't need to crop anything yet, it's all one image with a grid and I need scrolling

Comment: Larme, now I need to put a grid over the photo. How can I make a grid?

Comment: @YLP - add a `CAShapeLayer` ... white stroke color ... create the grid path with move-to / add-line-to / move-to / add-line-to / etc..

Comment: I need to do it through a collection it's much harder to do through the CAShapeLayer and you have to calculate everything

Comment: @YLP - *"I need to do it through a collection"* ... it will be ***much more difficult*** to cut the image into "grid sub-images" for use with a collection view than to use a `CAShapeLayer`... Is there something else you're planning on doing with the "image tiles"?

Comment: DonMag, I just need the grid for now [link] (https://files.fm/f/p5ybm85xp)

Comment: DonMag, how can I get this with the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a really quick example using a `CAShapeLayer`...

**UIImageView subclass**

```
class GridImageView: UIImageView {
    
    public var numRows: Int = 1
    public var numColumns: Int = 1
    
    private let gridLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        layer.addSublayer(gridLayer)
        gridLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        gridLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gridLayer.lineWidth = 1
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        if numRows == 1 && numColumns == 1 {
            // no need to draw any lines
            gridLayer.path = nil
            return
        }
        
        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        
        if numRows > 1 {
            let yIncrement: CGFloat = bounds.height / CGFloat(numRows)
            var y: CGFloat = yIncrement
            for _ in 0..<numRows-1 {
                bez.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: y))
                bez.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: y))
                y += yIncrement
            }
        }
        
        if numColumns > 1 {
            let xIncrement: CGFloat = bounds.width / CGFloat(numColumns)
            var x: CGFloat = xIncrement
            for _ in 0..<numColumns-1 {
                bez.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: bounds.minY))
                bez.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: bounds.maxY))
                x += xIncrement
            }
        }
        
        gridLayer.path = bez.cgPath
    }
}
```

**Example Controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "beach") else { return }
        
        let imgView = GridImageView(image: img)
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: img.size.height / img.size.width)
        ])
        
        imgView.numRows = 4
        imgView.numColumns = 3
        
    }
    
}
```

Output (using a random beach jpg):

[image]

---

**Edit** - *after further comments on OP...*

To get the "effect" from the video you posted, we can simply add a "grid overlay view" on top of the scroll view.

So, we'll use an almost identical subclassed `UIView`:

```
class GridOverlayView: UIView {
    
    public var lineColor: UIColor = .white { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var numRows: Int = 1 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var numColumns: Int = 1 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    private let gridLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        layer.addSublayer(gridLayer)
        gridLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gridLayer.lineWidth = 1
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        if numRows == 1 && numColumns == 1 {
            // no need to draw any lines
            gridLayer.path = nil
            return
        }
        
        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        
        if numRows > 1 {
            let yIncrement: CGFloat = bounds.height / CGFloat(numRows)
            var y: CGFloat = yIncrement
            for _ in 0..<numRows-1 {
                bez.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: y))
                bez.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: y))
                y += yIncrement
            }
        }
        
        if numColumns > 1 {
            let xIncrement: CGFloat = bounds.width / CGFloat(numColumns)
            var x: CGFloat = xIncrement
            for _ in 0..<numColumns-1 {
                bez.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: bounds.minY))
                bez.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: bounds.maxY))
                x += xIncrement
            }
        }
        
        gridLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
        gridLayer.path = bez.cgPath
    }
}
```

with this "beach" image:

[image]

and this controller class with a scroll view:

```
class GridScrollTestVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "beach") else { return }

        imgView.image = img
        
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: img.size.height / img.size.width)
            
        ])
        
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
        
        // now let's add the grid "overlay"
        let gridView = GridOverlayView()
        gridView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(gridView)
        gridView.numRows = 4
        gridView.numColumns = 3
        gridView.lineColor = .black
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            gridView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            gridView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            gridView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            gridView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        // don't let the grid overlay view interfere with the scrolling/zooming
        gridView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
    }
    
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imgView
    }
    
}
```

and we get this output:

[image]

and after zooming in a bit:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need, I need both horizontal and vertical scrolling of content yet

Comment: @YLP - OK... the video you added is ***very different*** from your question. See the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: @YLP - and, after you showed what you're really trying to do, a collection view is absolutely ***NOT*** what you want to try to use.

Comment: is different because I didn't say scrolling, in UICollectionView it is already implied that there will be scrolling. I am advised to do it with flow layout

Comment: can you please send me the link github to the project?

Comment: @YLP - https://github.com/DonMag/GridOverlay

Comment: please tell me if this solution can be built into the storyboard ?)

Comment: @YLP - I updated the GitHub repo to show using it with Storyboard

Comment: thank you so much, I found my mistake, I don't know how to thank you:)

Comment: and please tell me how to make the grid a square instead of a rectangle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249251/discussion-between-donmag-and-ylp).

Comment: sorry to bother you I have a question, can you please help me? Could you please come back to our chat room

Comment: Hi. Sorry to bother you again, I need your help, could you please come back to our conversation?